# Default mail sender with Swiftmailer on Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

I'm desperately trying to send several emails using the same email address configured as following on config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
    swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    sender_address : example@example.com
    spool: { type: memory }
```

The problem is, I can't find out how to use that particular sender_address parameter. The Symfony documentation says that if defined, it will be set automatically

```
    $new_campaign_mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Test')
        ->setTo($user->getEmail())
        ->setBody($this->templating->render('AcmeBundle:Default:email.html.twig', array('data' => $object, 'user' => $user)), 'text/html');

 /* Is that useful ?
    $this->container->get('swiftmailer.plugin.impersonate'); */

    $this->mailer->send($new_campaign_mail);
```

Thanks everyone ! :)

Comment: You can try to fetch the sender_address parameter, if you're working in the controller you just have to call $this->getParameter('sender_address'); and then put it on the setFrom() method of the Swift_Message instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch that parameter `sender_address` and add it like:

```
    $new_campaign_mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setFrom($your_sender_address_parameter)
    ->setSubject('Test')
    ->setTo($user->getEmail())
    ->setBody($this->templating->render('AcmeBundle:Default:email.html.twig', array('data' => $object, 'user' => $user)), 'text/html');
```

You can find out [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html) how to get parameter, basically if you are doing this in controller `$this->getParameter('sender_address');` or you can inject it in service as:

```
services:
    app.service.mail:
        class:  AppBundle\Service\MailService
        arguments: [%sender_address%]
```

**EDIT:**

I just read your post one more time and I see that there is an option in swiftmailer for sender address but I do not think that it is what you are looking for as this is the explanation that can be read [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#sender-address):

> If set, all messages will be delivered with this address as the
>   "return path" address, which is where bounced messages should go. This
>   is handled internally by Swift Mailer's
>   Swift_Plugins_ImpersonatePlugin class.

Comment: Yeah I Saw that option but I can't figure out how to use it properly...

Comment: @3615_Internet you can try the solution I posted in the first part of answer as that works for me.